# Can anyone point me to good development environment in Linux for client side search with Flex or JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, development, flex, linux, boundless-suite

I want to create a client in MapFish, and/or opengeo, using OpenLayers, maybe Cartaro and would like to play in a development environment using Flex or JavaScript.

I need to take my data, make it searchable from table columns and features, and be able to search strings for geolocation content, any good tuts, links, or Linux development environments that you could recommend?

Answer (score 2):

developement environment:

[aptana](http://www.aptana.com/) is pretty good free IDE for html, javascript, ruby and python.

Web IDE's "in the cloud" are getting very good and work on Linux obviously:

[maqetta](http://www.maqetta.org/) is web IDE + interface builder for dojo+html, also free

[codiqa](http://www.codiqa.com/) is also a web IDE + interface builder, but for jquery, but not free

Tutorials:

Opengeo's tutorial on open-layers is not bad:
http://workshops.opengeo.org/openlayers-intro/index.html

For searching in content in a layer, the dojo object-store might be a solution: 
http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.8/intro_dojo_store/
http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.8/creating_stores/
http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.8/selects_using_stores/

Comment: To add to this, QGIS is the desktop GIS software that I would recommend you use if you need to create data.  As far as a spatially enabled databases go, look at Postgres (POST GIS) or Spatailite (SQLite based).

Comment: oh yes, dojo + openlayers, also useful:  http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dojox/geo/openlayers.html

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you download sublime... It can be used with most coding languages and does syntax highlighting, etc.

Give it a try and see if it works for you.

Site: http://www.sublimetext.com/2

It's just an archive, so extract it and then run the .sh file in it. It will then open. You can always extract it to /sbin/sublime and then run it from terminal by typing sublime...